# How Do I Add A rel="nofollow" to shortcode

Tags: html, wordpress

How do I add a `nofollow` tag to this shortcode on my `wordpress` website.

```
[button href="https://geni.us/ZauBS" bg_color="#d32e2e" bg_hover="#000000" text_color="#ffffff" text_hover="#f7d52c" target="1"] BUY FROM AMAZON [/button]
```

I tried doing this it didn't work.

```
[button href="https://geni.us/ZauBS" rel="nofollow" bg_color="#d32e2e" bg_hover="#000000" text_color="#ffffff" text_hover="#f7d52c" target="1"] BUY FROM AMAZON [/button]

[button href="https://geni.us/ZauBS"" bg_color="#d32e2e" bg_hover="#000000" text_color="#ffffff" text_hover="#f7d52c" target="1"] BUY FROM AMAZON [/button]
```

Comment: If that didn't work, you'll need to edit the code that registers the shortcode itself to add it directly there or to include a new `rel` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to modify the underlying code for the shortcode itself.

Somewhere in your project, `button` is being registered as a shortcode (https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode). That could be within a plugin or a theme that you're using.

When a shortcode is registered, the code will determine what attributes it's going to accept. In your case it appears to be things like `bg_hover`, `text_color`, and so forth. Any attributes you pass in that aren't on that list are simply ignored.

In order for `button` to recognise the `rel` attribute, you would need to update the code to handle that.

Unfortunately it sounds like the shortcode is being registered in *code that you don't own*. What I mean by that is it may be part of a third-party plugin or theme that will need to be kept up to date therefore you aren't in a position to modify at will. Modifications made to such code will be overwritten by future updates.

If that is the case, one option would be to find and copy the code into your own plugin. Then use `remove_shortcode()` / `add_shortcode()` to override the behaviour of that one particular shortcode. Keep in mind that while this avoids updates replacing your code, it still leads to a somewhat fragile setup. If an update affects the button shortcode, you'll need to be aware and update your own code to reflect any changes that have been made.

Answer (score 1):

It's very hard to say with data given taking into account that the shortcode gets converted to html on screen.

What you could do is target outgoing links via JS.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $('a[target="_blank"]').attr('rel', 'nofollow');
});
```

I have not tested this but see if it helps in your situation.

Comment: Where can I paste this Javascript

Comment: In you theme's js file.